# Why Elasticsearch search query returns hits always empty?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am trying to get index data from my elasticsearch with below code. But always result is 0. How can I do that ? my below query returns me empty result.

```
            var list = new List<Monitor>();
            if (_client.IndexExists(indexName).Exists)
            {
                var esurl = "http://monitoring1.xxx.software:9200/,http://monitoring2.xxx.software:9200/";
                string[] urls = esurl.Split(',');
                var nodes = new Uri[2];

                for (int i = 0; i < urls.Length; i++)
                {
                    nodes.SetValue(new Uri(urls[i]), i);
                }

                var connectionPool = new SniffingConnectionPool(nodes);
                var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(connectionPool).DefaultIndex(indexName)
                                    .SniffOnConnectionFault(false)
                                    .SniffOnStartup(false)
                                    .SniffLifeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

                var hits = client.Search<Monitor>(s => s.Index(indexName)).Hits;

                QueryContainer query = new TermQuery
                {
                    Field = "DbName",
                    Value = "Mydb"
                };

                var searchRequest = new SearchRequest
                {
                    From = 0,
                    Size = 10,
                    Query = query
                };

                var searchResults = client.Search<Monitor>(searchRequest);// Result => 0

                list = client.Search<Monitor>(s=>s.Index(indexName)).Hits.Select(q => q.Source).ToList<Monitor>(); // Result => 0 again
            }
            return list;
```

```
**
```

> Below code is related to my mapping. I think  that it is helpful.

**

```js
{
    "took": 5,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 4,
        "max_score": 1.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "monitorsystemdetail-2019",
                "_type": "monitorsystemdetailtype",
                "_id": "989d7859-3f43-48d2-a978-edb7aaa4c1af",
                "_score": 1.0,
                "_source": {
                    "logDate": "2019-12-04T12:58:34Z",
                    "totalVisitorCountLast5minutes": 120,
                    "totalVisitorCountLast1Hour": 803,
                    "totalRequestCountLast5Minutes": 1661,
                    "totalRequestCountLast1Hour": 25768,
                    "timeStamp": "4.12.2019 13:58:26",
                    "problemId": "Script error.",
                    "operationName": "/",
                    "customDimensions": "{\"url\":\"https://www.xxx.com.tr/\"}",
                    "timeStamp2": "4.12.2019 13:58:25",
                    "problemId2": "Script error.",
                    "operationName2": "/",
                    "customDimensions2": "{\"url\":\"https://www.xxx.com.tr/\"}",
                    "dbName": "TourismDb",
                    "bufferPage": 2659249.0,
                    "dbBufferUsedMB": 20775.0,
                    "dbBufferFreeMB": 0.0,
                    "dbBufferPercent": 96.153,
                    "dbBufferPercentAverage": 0.0
                }
            },
           
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "duplicateCount": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
        }
    }
}
```

Result like that:

[image]

Comment: Can you show a sample document that should match, as well as the mapping of the `DbName` field?

Comment: @AssaelAzran said it all :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DbName` is probably of type `text` and you are using  `TermQuery`.

If you want to use `TermQuery` to find `DbName` as exact match then you should change

`Field = "DbName"` to `Field = "DbName.keyword"` (change your mappings accordingly), otherwise change `TermQuery` to `MatchQuery`.

**Mappings**

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "DbName": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update Index - when updating your mappings**

```
POST my_index/_update_by_query? 
conflicts=proceed
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you your answer; but not working your solution.

Comment: QueryContainer query = new TermQuery
                {
                    Field = "DbName.keyword",
                    Value = "TourismDb"
                };  NOT WORKED

Comment: Did you update your mappings with the `keyword` type or it has already existed? If you updated your mapping then a `reindex` is required.

Comment: this is true?  {
    "source": {
      "index": "'monitorsystem-*'"
    },
    "dest": {
      "index": "'monitorsystem-*'-reindexed"
    }
  }

Comment: Result: it's the same. I think I am doing wrong something.

Comment: You can run this `POST monitorsystem/_update_by_query?conflicts=proceed` instead.